# Why isinstance() dosen't behave as I except?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to creat a function to find the root of the quadratic equation,and I have used isinstance() to make sure that number had been entered.But it dosen't work as I except.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    if not isinstance(a(int, float),b(int, float),c(int, float)):
        raise TypeError('please enter integer or decimal')
```

The error is :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4wj.png)

Comment: ```a(int, float)```. ```a``` is an ```int```. Python thinks you're trying to use it as a function with two arguments: ```int``` and ```float```.

Comment: @Take_Care_ when someone is learning something and is new to it, some stuff that seem obvious to us (more experienced people) might not be so obvious to that new person. The second part of your comment is helpful. The first a little less...

Comment: you could do something like `if not all([isinstance(v, (int, float)) for v in (a,b,c)]):`